# Having issues pulling a GET value from a URL, Not sure what I'm doing wrong

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm working on a link disclaimer page for internal use and on of the issues I'm having is getting the outgoing URL into the link on the page. The code below is what I'm using to grab the GET value I need and put it in the link's href attribut after decoding. The other half of the code uses the built-in Javascript encodeURIComponent() function, so unless I can use the PHP decode function, or if there's a dead simple way to grab the GET value I need using Javascript, I'm going to use PHP to place it in the Javascript on the server side. I know it works and it only takes a few lines of PHP code to grab and validate what I need.

That said, the code is below and I'll also provide a link to the page so you can see what's going on.

```
jQuery(".btn-continue").attr("href") = "\"" + decodeURIComponent(
    <?php 
        if(isset($_GET["outlink"])){
            echo $_GET["outlink"];
        }else{
            echo "/";
        }
    ?>
);
```

This is the page that has the code in action: http://radboxstudio.com/you-are-now-leaving-radboxstudio-com.html?outlink=http://google.com/

Clicking the first link to Google on this page should take you to the page above: http://radboxstudio.com/

There's a bit of Javascript that is supposed to encode the link's href and pass it on using get. I've included the relevant code below in case I screwed up there. currentDomain is defined in an earlier bit of code and I know that works as it is supposed to.

```
$('a').each(function() {
        var $a  = jQuery(this);

        if ($a.get(0).hostname && getDomain($a.get(0).hostname) != currentDomain) {
            $a.click(function(event) {
                if (!confirmed) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    var url = encodeURIComponent($a.get(0));
                    window.location = "http://radboxstudio.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=10&outlink=" + url; 

                }
            });
        }
});
```

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)). User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: @Quentin Can you explain where and how the vulnerability is? I'm afraid I'm not seeing it and I need to plug this ASAP.

Comment: `echo $_GET["outlink"];`

Comment: @Quentin I think I fixed this. The revised code is '<?php if(isset($_GET["outlink"])){$outlink = htmlspecialchars($_GET["outlink"]);}else{$outlink = "/";}?>'

Answer (score 0):

To set the value of href by using the attr() function of jquery you should use it like this:

```
$("selector").attr("href", "value_you_want");
```

Checkout jquery api: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: I did try that after I posted this here. I found out that PHP automatically decodes GET parameters that have been encoded. I just grabbed the parameter and output it in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the PHP was doing the work for me. The code below works.

```
<?php if(isset($_GET["outlink"])){
    $outlink = $_GET["outlink"];
}else{
    $outlink = "/";
}
?>
<a href="<?php echo $outlink;?>">Linky</a>
```

Sorry for the trouble. :D

Comment: As pointed out in a comment above, this is open to an XSS attack. To fix this, use the following PHP to get the URL '<?php if(isset($_GET["outlink"])){$outlink = htmlspecialchars($_GET["outlink"]);}else{$outlink = "/";}?>'